# Expected Value of a 2-Player Dice Game

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, expected-value, dice

This question has been posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487975/30-sided-die-and-20-sided-die) before, but I am not getting the correct answer following the intended solution, so I'd like some insight. Reposting for clarity:

Two people, $A$ and $B$, have a 30-sided and 20-sided die, respectively. Each rolls their die, and the person with the highest roll wins. ($B$ also wins in the event of a tie.) The loser pays the winner the value on the winner's die. How does the expected value of the game for player $A$ change when player $B$ can re-roll?

So, I've confirmed that $B$ should re-roll in the case that (s)he rolls some value $v
$ such that $v\leq11$. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in calculating the EV for $A$, though. Assuming one re-roll, I have

$$EV_A = \frac{1}{30}[21+\cdots+30] - \frac{1}{30}\cdot(\frac{1}{9} + \frac{11}{20}\cdot\frac{1}{9})[12+\cdots+20] -  \frac{1}{30}\cdot(\frac{11}{20}\cdot\frac{1}{11})[1+\cdots+11]=7.5633$$

However, the correct answer is $5.4275$.

Secondly, what if $B$ was allowed as many as re-rolls as (s)he wants? Would the $EV$ for $A$ be

$$EV_A = \frac{1}{30}[21+\cdots+30] - \frac{1}{30}\cdot\frac{1}{9}[12+\cdots+20] - \frac{1}{30}[1+\cdots+11]=5.766$$

This is because $B$ is guaranteed to land in the range $12-20$; hence, if $A$ rolls between $1-11$, (s)he is surely to lose. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Does $B$ know $A$'s score before deciding whether or not to re-roll?  In any case, if $B$ can reroll as often as desired then $B$ will (eventually) get a $20$, so it's easy to compute the probabilities.

Comment: Nope, $B$ re-rolls without knowing $A$'s result.

Comment: So, then you can get a complete distribution of $B's$ value.  Since the distribution of $A's$ value is easy to get (and the two are independent) we can then read off the joint distribution, which should make the computation straight forward (if a bit messy).

Comment: Why do you say that $B$ should reroll on $11$?  $B's$ expectation is $10.5$ so $11$ should be a winner, no?

Comment: $B$ wants to minimize his loss. We should take into account $A$'s roll as well, so the answer isn't as simple as 10.5 - I wrote $A$'s EV in terms of $B$'s roll $b$: $\frac{b}{30}[-b] + \frac{1}{30}[(b+1)+\ldots+30]$. We simplify and note that we want it to be greater than the unconditioned EV for $A$, which is $\frac{1}{3}({25.5})-\frac{1}{20}\frac{2}{3}({10.5})=8.15$, which gives $-\frac{b^2}{20}-\frac{b}{60}+\frac{31}{2}>\frac{163}{20}.$ Solving gives $b\leq11$. If $b\geq12$, $A$'s profit ($B$'s loss) is less than the unconditioned EV 8.15, so he should reroll until he gets $b\geq12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_\limits{x=1}^{20}\sum_\limits{y=x+1}^{30}\ P(X=x)P(Y=y)y-\sum_\limits{x=1}^{20}\sum_\limits{y=1}^{x}\ P(X=x)P(Y=y)x$

Without re-rolls

$\frac 1{600}\sum_\limits{x=1}^{20} \frac {(30+x+1)(30-x)}{2}-x^2\\
\frac 1{600}\sum_\limits{x=1}^{20} \frac {(30)(31)-x^2-x}{2} - x^2\\
\frac 1{600}\sum_\limits{x=1}^{20} 465 -\frac {3}{2}x^2 - \frac 12 x\\
\frac 1{600}(465*20 - \frac {20(21)(41)}{4}-\frac {(20)(21)}{4})\\
\frac 1{600}(465*20 - \frac {20(21)(42)}{4})=8.15
$

Allowing for a reroll.

$P(X=x) = \begin{cases} \frac {1}{40} & x\le 10\\\frac {3}{40} & x>10\end{cases}$

$\frac {1}{1200}(\sum_\limits{x=1}^{10}\sum_\limits{y=x+1}^{30}y-\sum_\limits{x=1}^{10}\sum_\limits{y=1}^{x}x+\frac {3}{1200}(\sum_\limits{x=11}^{20}\sum_\limits{y=x+1}^{30}y-\sum_\limits{x=11}^{20}\sum_\limits{y=1}^{x}x)\\
\frac 1{1200}\sum_\limits{x=1}^{10} 465 -\frac {3}{2}x^2 - \frac 12 x+3(\sum_\limits{x=11}^{20} 465 -\frac {3}{2}x^2 - \frac 12 x)\\
\frac 1{1200}((465*10 - \frac {10(11)(22)}{4}) + 3(465*10 - \frac {20(21)(42))}{4}+\frac {10(11)(22))}{4})\\
\frac 1{1200}((465*40 + \frac {10(11)(22)}{2} - 3\frac {20(21)(42)}{4})\approx 5.48$

For multiple re-rolls, you just need to work out the PDF for $X$.